# Android: Multiple choice select list - Check the checkbox only when the checkbox is seleted and not on text-view

Tags: java, android

I'm ceating a multiple_choice List View which shows names of Directories.
Since it is multiple-choice select, each item contains a textview and a checkbox.
By default when I click on any item, the checkbox gets selected/deselected.
This is not the functionality I want.
Since, I'm showing names of directories, I want when the user clicks on the item, instead of the checkbox getting selected, a new list should be displayed containing the name of sub-folder of that directory.

In simple terms, when the textview of the item is selected a new list should get displayed & when the the check box is selected then only the check box should be checked/unchecked.

Below, is my code till now:

```
public class DirectoryListing extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ListView dirlv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.directorylisting);
        try {
            ArrayList<String> dirList = new ArrayList<String>();
            dirList = getAllDirList();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                    android.R.id.text1, dirList);
            dirlv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDirList);
            dirlv.setAdapter(adapter);
            dirlv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            dirlv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private ArrayList<String> getAllDirList() {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        File home = new File("/");
        File[] files = home.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                result.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        try {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            //TODO
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you think this will mislead your users? Everytime you see a list item with a checkbox you presume that clicking on it will check/uncheck that checkbox. Try to avoid unintuitive behavior.

Comment: I thought of that too..but I need this functionality. I tried expandable too but if there are many recursive sub-folders then it will look terrible. Any suggestions.

Comment: If I understand your logic properly, you need to select multiple files, so you should find a way to put checkboxes only on list items that represent files, not directories. So, clicking a folder will expand that folder, and clicking a file will check/uncheck it.

Comment: ummmmm...actually I'm building this for image files & there are just too many image files. I do not want user to select each and every file, that's why. There is an application viz. MoboPlayer, it has exactly what I need for folder scanning.

Comment: Then it's easier to implement some kind of Select All functionality